# How much do Autosofts cost?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I was not able to find the cost of Rigging Autosofts (like Clearshight, Maneuvering and Targeting) in the rulebook.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [errata](http://www.shadowruntabletop.com/2014/02/shadowrun-fifth-edition-errata-now-available/) finally came out:

```
 Program/Software | Avail      | Cost
 Autosoft         | Rating x 2 | Rating x 500¥
```

Answer (score 2):

The Corebook describes Autosofts as:

> Autosofts are specialized programs designed to increase
>   the effectiveness of a drone’s performance. In
>   other words, people have skills, drones have autosofts.
>   An autosoft is rated between 1 and 6. - P. 269

Because of this description, and the lack of any pricing table related directly to Autosofts, I would treat them as Programs and us the Program/Software cost table to decide the cost of an Auto Soft

[image]

- P. 442

Comment: The most similar programs are the agents, but the pricing would be quite unbalanced, as the Rigger needs to buy the Autosofts separately for every kind of drone he uses.
Tutorsoft pricing would make more sense.

Comment: @András I highly suggest you check the official forums. I'm not a heavy shadowrun player, but my friends who are big fans all agree that 5th edition is a bit of a mess with the 1st rules version.

Comment: I disagree, knowing how many problems I saw in 3rd and 4th when they came out.  But, I digress.  I would use Hacking Program costs with a rating multiplier, and have them be 2 x rating R for availability, because this seems the most fair while allowing them to be bought at char gen.